# React Native: image inside bottom curved inner view

Tags: react-native

in my react native app I want to have a screen exactly like the one in my image, basically its an image inside a container with a masked view on top, but i don't know how to do it, I tried playing with border radius and overflow hidden but I could not get the desired results...

Image:
https://i.imgur.com/gukMc5z.jpg

```
<View style={{ width:'100%',height:root.uiStore.height*0.6,position:'relative',borderRadius:25,overflow:'hidden',marginVertical:20,elevation:5, position:'relative  }}>
            
                <FastImage style={{ width:'100%',height:'100%', elevation:0, marginTop:0,position:'relative',zIndex:1,overflow:'hidden' }} resizeMode="cover" source={{uri: env.BASE_URL+active_user.images[2] }}/>
            </View>
```

Is it possible to achieve without downloading any extra modules?

Answer (score 0):

```
import React from 'react';
import { View, Image } from 'react-native';

const YourComponent = ({ active_user, env }) => {
  return (
    <View
      style={{
        width: '100%',
        height: root.uiStore.height * 0.6,
        position: 'relative',
        borderRadius: 25,
        overflow: 'hidden',
        marginVertical: 20,
        elevation: 5,
        position: 'relative',
      }}
    >
      <Image
        style={{
          width: '100%',
          height: '100%',
          marginTop: 0,
          position: 'relative',
          zIndex: 1,
          overflow: 'hidden',
        }}
        resizeMode="cover"
        source={{ uri: env.BASE_URL + active_user.images[2] }}
      />
    </View>
  );
};

export default YourComponent;
```

This code snippet assumes that you have the necessary data (active_user and env) passed as props to your component and that root.uiStore.height is accessible. Also, make sure to replace root.uiStore.height with an appropriate height value if it's not defined in your code.